# cakephp cms with sqlserver error

Tags: php, cakephp, content-management-system, croogo, quickapps-cms

I have tried to setup  both quickapp -cms and croogo- cms with cake php 2.8.6 and sqlserver 2016 . It works fine with mysql but failed with sql server . I encounter following error :

```
cake php 2.8.6
php 5.6.23
Ms sql server
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      13.0.15700.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        13.0.1700.68
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.2.9200.16384
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.10.9200.17607
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.2.9200

====================================================================================
Unable to connect to database, please check your information. Details:
Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid encoding was specified for SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING.


================================================================================
```

My db config :

```
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'COLLONMADE\SQLEXPRESS',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'cro',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042778/cakephp-sqlserver-encoding

Comment: I already tried it but problem still persists

Comment: Try to change the encoding value, i.e `UTF8`, `utf-8`, `iso_1`, etc

Comment: @sємsєм Its also not working . I also added  collation same displayed in database properties . but failed . :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution which is not optimum As I think but works in my case . Thanks all to answer this question . I have tried this with [croogo cms](https://croogo.org/) version 1.4.3 and 1.5.8 both works perfectly .

go to myapp\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Sqlserver.php

and comment out flags lines as below :

```
/*$flags = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $config['persistent'],
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        if (!empty($config['encoding'])) {
            $flags[PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING] = $config['encoding'];
        }*/

        try {
            $this->_connection = new PDO(
                "sqlsrv:server={$config['host']};Database={$config['database']}",
                $config['login'],
                $config['password']
                //$flags
            );
```

After this change you will able to go to next step where in croogo you will get internal server error which is because it has not created settings table so go to:

```
config/schema/sql/croogo.sql
```

and copy insert query of settings table and execute in your database.

now again go to install procedure you will be able to finish all steps and login .